# What fs-type should I use in parted when creating an exFAT partition?

Tags: filesystems, parted, exfat

When I try to create a partition with parted and a filesystem type of 'exFAT', I encounter the following error:

`parted: invalid token: exFAT`

What fs-type should I use when creating a partition destined for an exFAT filesystem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**NTFS**

I discovered the answer in the man page for the mkfs.exfat utility, which states:

`Note that if this is an MBR partition then the file system type should be set to 0x07 (NTFS/exFAT) otherwise other operating systems may refuse to mount the file system.`

In `parted`, this is accomplished with the 'NTFS' fs-type.

Answer (score 1):

0x**07** when using *fdisk*.

You can list all supported partitions type with the command: **l**